# onCLickListener for ImageView works slow

Tags: android

First, I created an Object called Card, which represents an image for card game.
Then, I created a function that receives a Vector of Cards, and draws the images on the screen.

Now, let me explain 2 scenarios that are happening, one works fast, and the other works slow.

## 1

When I create the Card Vector, I create new card and add it to the vector one by one like this:

```
    vect.add(new Card(1, '\u2660'));  
    vect.add(new Card(2, '\u2660'));  
    vect.add(new Card(3, '\u2660'));  
    vect.add(new Card(8, '\u2660'));  
    vect.add(new Card(9, '\u2660'));  
    drawCards(vect);
```

That way, everything works fast.

## 2

In the second scenario, which I want to use:
I have another Card Vector that is created at another place in the code. and I send that Vector to my drawCards() function. but then it works slowly.

```
    drawCards(players[0].cards);
```

my drawCards function:

```
void drawCards(Vector<Card> myCards) {
    myCardsLayout.removeAllViews();
    for (Card card1 : myCards) {
        final Card card = card1;
        final ImageView image = new ImageView(this);
        final String cardStr = card.cardToString();
        Resources res = getResources();
        int resID = res.getIdentifier(cardStr, "drawable", getPackageName());
        image.setImageResource(resID);
        image.setLayoutParams(selfLayoutParams);

        image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (myTurn) {
                    if (currentPlayCardsVector.contains(card)) {
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
                        lp.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
                        image.setLayoutParams(lp);
                        currentPlayCardsVector.remove(card);
                    } else {
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
                        lp.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 20);
                        image.setLayoutParams(lp);
                        currentPlayCardsVector.add(card);
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please wait for your turn", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

        myCardsLayout.addView(image);
    }
}
```

I would like to mention that drawing the images on the beginning is ok, but when the image is being clicked, it is very slow to respond and move the image (in the 2nd scenario).
Thanks.

Comment: Show other vector code, and what are you doing whit this vecors in code. I will be somthing in draw method i think...

Comment: Show draw method pls

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure exactly on how to answer this question, but it seems like the performance of your method 2 may be effected by where you have placed the code. Code placement is a key factor in development. Once, my app was very unresponsive, and then I made a change and then it ran a lot more fast.  Also, you could try closing up background services that are not being used, such as for example if you are on a second activity, finish() your first activity.  I hope that helps.